# Create folders from filename pattern and move the files to these folders

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I want to create a batch file / windows command for the following scenario:

I have a list of files in a folder with a particular filename pattern say ...  **XXXX_XX**
where **X** is mostly a number.
The main catch here is that the position of this pattern isn't actually fixed and could occur anywhere within the filename.

For Example:

These are filenames:
1. ABCD-33-21234-**4652_00**-2017-03.txt
2. SECA-11-**4652_00**-2017-03.txt
3. 8888-asde0-dswc-33-**4444_55**-2016-05.txt

I need to move these files into directories (create them if not existing) with names **XXXX_XX**

so basically i need to move them into folders as:

....**\4652_00\**ABCD-33-21234-**4652_00**-2017-03.txt
....**\4652_00\**SECA-11-**4652_00**-2017-03.txt
....**\4444_55\**8888-asde0-dswc-33-**4444_55**-2016-05.txt

I have tried a lot but could'nt get a solution. Appreciate your help.

Comment: As [SO] isn't a script writing service you should show the effort you have put into coding to get help where you got stuck. The varying elements delimited with a `-` make it difficult to parse in batch as there is no real RegEx feature. But you could use j-/vbscipt or PowerShell for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cmd line solution wrapping a PowerShell one liner.
Used in a batch, the `%`-sign has to be doubled `%%`.

Sample output on my ram disk A:

```
> tree /F
A:.
    8888-asde0-dswc-33-4444_55-2016-05.txt
    ABCD-33-21234-4652_00-2017-03.txt
    SECA-11-4652_00-2017-03.txt
```

---

```
powershell -NoP -C "dir *.txt|where {$_.BaseName -match '-(\d{4}_\d{2})-20'}|%{MD $matches[1] -EA 0;$_|Move -Dest {$matches[1]}}"
```

---

```
> tree /F
A:.
├───4444_55
│       8888-asde0-dswc-33-4444_55-2016-05.txt
└───4652_00
        ABCD-33-21234-4652_00-2017-03.txt
        SECA-11-4652_00-2017-03.txt
```

Essential is the Regular Expression `-(\d{4}_\d{2})-20` which matches the pattern -xxxx_xx-20 and the parentheses around (xxxx_xx) mark the group we are interested in.

A more verbose version without aliases of the PowerShell script:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt |
  Where-Object BaseName -Match  '-(\d{4}_\d{2})-20'|
    ForEach-Object {
      mkdir $matches[1] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
      $_ | Move-Item -Destination {$matches[1]}
    }
```

Comment: At line:1 char:49
+ Dir *.pdf|? BaseName -match '-(\d{4}_\d{2})-20'|{MD $matches[1] -EA 0;$_|Move -D ...
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline

Comment: What powershell version do you have? `$psversiontable`

Comment: I don't know quite anything about powershell. How can I find the version. It is major : 3, minor : 0

Comment: I did a small syntax change to comply with PS version 2+. Copy the complete line between the two tree's into a cmd window. Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*-????_??-*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
 SET "filename=!filename:-= !"
 SET "moved="
 FOR %%b IN (!filename!) DO IF NOT DEFINED moved (
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%p IN ("%%b") DO IF "%%q" neq "" (
   ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%p_%%q" 2>NUL
   ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%p_%%q\"
   SET "moved=Y"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

The `dir` command returns each filename that matches the filemask to `%%a`, thence to `filename`.

Each `-` in `filename` is then replaced by a space and the `for..%%b` process the filename as a list of space-separated strings.

Each string in `%%b` is tokenised and the first string matching *string*_*string* is assigned to `%%p` and `%%q`. If `%%q` is non-empty, then we have found *string*_*string* so do the `md` and `move` and set the `moved` flag to ensure that further matches found are ignored.

Note that this will not deal with the situation where you have a filename like *something*-abc_d-EFGH_JK-*something* - it assumes that the required destination is the first appearance of *string*_*string* which in this case would be `abc_d`, not `EFGH_JK`. This is easy to fix if required.

---

Revision in the light of correction to filename structure (no underscores - dashes only)

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\????-*-????-??-*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
 CALL :newname !filename:-= !

 IF DEFINED newdir (
  ECHO MD "!newdir!" 2>NUL
  ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\!newdir!\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:newname
IF "%5" neq "" shift&GOTO newname
SET "newdir=%1-%2"
IF "%newdir:~4,1%" equ "-" IF "%newdir:~7%" equ "" IF "%newdir:~6,1%" neq "" GOTO :EOF
SET "newdir="
GOTO :eof
```

New code looks for a the sequence -????-??-*string*-*string* and picks the last of these.

Comment: Thanks. But the code seems to be creating a folder for each file in the directory with the same name as that of the file instead of grouping them into folders of the format ????_??

Comment: Please provide examples. The code `echo`ed the correct creations and moves for me.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the filenames are actually having more underscores (_) rather than dashes (-)

Comment: I guess I actually put up my scenario incorrectly. Your code works perfectly fine for the scenario that i mentioned. But the actual case is that the dashes (-) are underscores(_). Thanks a lot for your help. If possible could you please provide a workout for that too?